# Insert values in class without explicit writing them

Tags: c#, class, testing, automation

I have some huge classes and don't want to write them all out for testing, because it's a huge effort and I could forget some values what makes the test invalid.

```
Messages = new List<Request.Notif.NotifRuleMessages>
{
    new Request.Notif.NotifRuleMessages
    {
        Code = 1234,
        Message = new List<Request.Notif.NotifRuleMessagesMessage>
        {
            new Request.Notif.NotifMessagesMessage
            {
                Status = new Request.Notif.NotifMessagesMessageStatus
                {
                    Code = 1,
                    Bool = true,
                    Test1 = "Test",
                    Test2 = "Test"
                },
                Rules = new List<Request.Notif.NotifMessagesMessageRule>
                {
                    new Request.Notif.NotifMessagesMessageRule
                    {
                        Lengths = new Request.Notif.NotifMessagesMessageRuleLength
                        {
                            Lenght = 1,
                            Lengths = new List<Request.Notif.NotifMessagesMessageRuleLengthLength>
                            {
                                new Request.Notif.NotifMessagesMessageRuleLengthLength
                                {
                                    Type = "Test",
                                    Value = 1
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        Status = new List<Request.Notif.NotifMessagesMessageRuleStatus>
                        {
                            new Request.Notif.NotifMessagesMessageRuleStatus
                            {
                                Test1 = "Test",
                                Test2 = "Test"
```

---

Is there a way to automaticly fill all `int` values with `1` or `0` and all `string` values with `Test` and especially all `objects` with the right class **without unit testing and external libs**?

Comment: Why do you think something will exist that *happens* to apply default values that *you* consider to be acceptable?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever because `{ get; set; }` exists too, which is unnecessary for pure coding and just helping the developer :) and may there is something to initialise the full class (with subclasses)

Comment: I think your best bet is to implement your own solution using reflection. I doubt there's a standard solution out there. One thing to be careful of is if your structures are recursive.

Comment: @Xerillio I can't imagine a solution with reflection, can you please give me an example? And nope, there is no recursion involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using reflection you could populate your objects recursively and set whatever default values you choose. A small example of a helper function that could do that for you:

```
void SetDefaults(object testObj)
{
    var props = testObj.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        if (prop.GetSetMethod() == null)
        {
            continue;
        }

        var propType = prop.PropertyType;
        if (propType == typeof(int))
        {
            prop.SetValue(testObj, 1);
        }
        else if (propType == typeof(bool))
        {
            prop.SetValue(testObj, false);
        }
        // More conditions...
        else
        {
            var ctor = propType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
            var propertyObject = ctor.Invoke(new object[0]);
            SetDefaults(propertyObject);
            prop.SetValue(testObj, propertyObject);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, if your tree of objects use types that don't have default constructors (parameterless constructors) you need some more complicated logic in the `else`-condition. Basically the stuff going on here is a very simplified version of what happens in a dependency injection framework.

To use it, do something like:

```
void Main()
{
    TestObject obj = new TestObject();
    SetDefaults(obj);

    Console.WriteLine(obj);
}

class TestObject {
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    public SubTestObject SubObj { get; set; }
}

class SubTestObject {
    public int MyOwnInt { get; set; }
    public bool MyBoolGetter => 1 > 0;
}
```

Comment: **This is fabulous!** But I'm getting an error whit a class were a `public bool ShouldSerializeName { return Name > 0; }` is. I think it's becouse it can't set a value to it. A `TargetParameterCountException` is thrown by the different args count. Any solution to this, the web can't help me with it.

Comment: @Daniel regarding `ShouldSerializeName`, depending on what you want to happen you can check if `prop.GetSetMethod() == null` and skip it. I'm not sure why you see `TargetParameterCountException` unless one of the classes has something like an indexer that takes multiple parameters. I would need a little more context to figure that out.

Comment: The `ShouldSerialize{Name}` variable identifys if the Variable `Name` should be serialized by the `XmlSerializer` but I will open [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54708110/property-setvalue-returns-targetparametercountexception) for that as it's not in the range of this one :)